# print full HTTP/2 gRPC response in Python

Tags: python, http, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have a gRPC server in Python and I am looking for a way to print the complete HTTP/2 response that it provides after receiving a request. Below is the method that receive the request and return a response.

```
@inject.params(storage='storage')
def getPerson(self, request,context=None, storage = None)
    logger.info('call of username {}'.format(
        request.username
    ))
    logger.info('Client Metadata {} '.format(
        context.invocation_metadata()
    ))

    response = mProto.Auth()
    response.value = 100
    logger.info('Client Metadata {} '.format(
        context.invocation_metadata()
    ))
    #some code
    response = storage.request(request.username, request.password)
    return response
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can enable debug logging in gRPC via environment variables defined [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/environment_variables.md). By setting `GRPC_VERBOSITY=DEBUG` and `GRPC_TRACE=http`, the server will print activity in its http2 stack. You'll have to sift through the output to find what you want.

Comment: Where I should write this line, please explain in the context of default python example provided by grpc-python. https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.48.1/examples/python/route_guide/asyncio_route_guide_server.py